# Индексатор в бинарном дереве поиска C#

Tags: c#, дерево

Сделал бинарное дерево поиска на C#, есть перечисление (`IEnumerable`) элементов в порядке возрастания.

Нужно сделать индексатор (`this[int i]`) который бы возвращал `i`-й по порядку элемент, при этом сложность должна быть `O(h)`, где `h` - высота дерева.

Нельзя просто возвращать `this.ElementAt(i)`, так как при этом сложность будет `O(n)`, где `n` - количество элементов в дереве.

Answer (score 1):

Храните для каждой вершины количество элементов в ее поддереве. Этой информации достаточно для быстрого поиска вершины по ее индексу.

Comment: А если по подробнее, что дает мне то, что я знаю количество элементов в поддереве?

Comment: Это даёт то, что по индексу ты теперь можешь определить, в какое поддерево идти - в левое или правое. В таком случае, ты найдёшь нужный элемент спустившись до листа без посещения других веток - это как раз та ассимптотика, которую ты хочешь.

Answer (score -1):

К сожалению, C# не предоставляет необходимую структуру, в отличие от других языков. Так что нужно реализовывать такое дерево самостоятельно.

Как достаточно простой вариант сбалансированного бинарного дерева, можно использовать рандомизированное декартово дерево с неявным ключом. Ассимптотика операций вставки, получения по индексу и удаления lb(n).